# typescript function header has only one argument but call requires 3

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a function in typescript with the following header:

```
export const func: AWSLambda.APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (
  arg
): Promise<AWSLambda.APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
```

When I try to call the function as part of a unit test though (like `func(param1)`), I get an error saying `Expected 3 arguments, but got 1. handler.d.ts(86,5): An argument for 'context' was not provided.`

Does anyone know why this requires 3 arguments, even though the function header only has one argument? Is it to do with the `AWSLambda.APIGatewayProxyHandler` or `Promise<AWSLambda.APIGatewayProxyResult>`?

Comment: please provide a link to the package

Comment: Could you share the test implementation?

Comment: the handler.d.ts file is from the AWS Lambda package https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/handler.d.ts. For context the ```func``` function is called when a specific lambda is invoked.

The test implementation is simply another function that calls the ```func``` function - I'm positive there's nothing specific about the way the test is set up that influences the way the function is called

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, this is how I do what youre trying to do. Im surprised your function definition isn't giving you a ts error?

```
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda'

export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (
  event,
  context,
  callback,
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  // Add logic here
}
```